# The way React works with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to React, and I have my first question about it. 
I have been told that what comes inside the "return" (The red line in the image) is HTML and if I want to use JS I need to open 
  { } and put the code inside it (Small white arrows in the image) so React "understand" its JS.
So again, only JS code will be inside { } 
 How come the `<li></li>` (blue line in the image) doesnt need to be surrounded by `` and the p.name need to be $p.name ? Cause its inside the {} and anything inside it should be JS!
So if I do need to put HTML inside { } is should be with string interpolation!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to React [document](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/javascript-in-jsx-with-curly-braces) regarding JSX syntax:

> Any JavaScript expression will work between curly braces { }

This also includes JSX tag, which is internally a syntactic sugar for a [function](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) that create elements.

Since `map()` returns a shadow copy of the array, the result of the following:

```
{["1", "2", "3"].map(item => <li key={item}>{`Product ${item}`}</li>)}
```

Returns something close to this, except that `map()` also requires adding unique `key` attributes to the output elements:

```
{[<li>Product 1</li>, <li>Product 2</li>, <li>Product 3</li>]}
```

And that is rendered close to as follows:

```
<li>Product 1</li>
<li>Product 2</li>
<li>Product 3</li>
```

More about rendering lists in React: [documents](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists)

Answer (score 0):

What you write React is not HTML itself, it is called JSX, which is a kind of HTML with some differences.

That's why you put it at the begging of your example `className`:

```html
<div className="ProductList">
```

instead of normal use normal `class` HTML

```html
<div class="myClass">`
```

So, technically, what you are writing all the time in JavaScript.
You can read more in [React JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)